# Safety of authentication configuration in Blazor WASM

Tags: authentication, blazor-webassembly, auth0

I'm super new to authentication schemes but have been implementing some basic Authentication and Authorization within a Blazor WASM application using Auth0 as a provider. [This guide by Andrea Chiarelli](https://auth0.com/blog/securing-blazor-webassembly-apps/) is what I followed to integrate my application with some kind of external authentication service and I have it working on my custom application very nicely.

My question is more around the security of having the "Authority", "ClientId" and "Audience" values specified directly in an appsettings.json config which is publicly visible as a file as part of the deployed application. Is this something that is potentially dangerous to expose? I'm not sure what a malicious actor or other parties could potentially do with references/IDs like that. If my question around security doesn't make sense to someone in the know with the way those fields interact with Auth0's systems, any explanation as to why exposing that data is safe would be great. Thanks!